# At what point do I need to add the X-UA Compatible meta tags?

Tags: c#, .net, meta, x-ua-compatible

I'm trying to add X-UA Compatible meta tags to my .net project by overriding a page method but I'm not exactly sure at what stage I need to add the tags. At the moment I have:

```
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        HtmlMeta meta = new HtmlMeta();
        meta.HttpEquiv = "X-UA-Compatible";
        meta.Content = "IE=EmulateIE7";
        Page.Header.Controls.Add(meta);
        base.OnInit(e);
    }
```

but this doesn't appear to be working. Do I have to add the tags before the page has initialized? On load? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this via the web.config:

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <httpProtocol>
         <customHeaders>
            <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=EmulateIE7" />
         </customHeaders>
      </httpProtocol>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Will work and requires no changes to your code.

More information: http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httpprotocol/customheaders

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply but this doesn't seem to work. The websites are not automatically displayed in compatibility mode

Comment: Have you examined the headers which are being returned?  You should be able to do so using the network tab in the development tools in the browser.  Or using some advanced tool like Fiddler.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, you should not add it.
Please check the [relevant MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676915.aspx) about specifying document models.